# C#: How to get my list of cards printing?

Tags: c#

I am trying to get my list of cards printing and so below I am saying let's just return the cards list version of `ToString()`:

```
  public override string ToString()
  {
      return Cards.ToString();
  }
```

So when I call `ToString()` on a list of cards, it will return a string representation of that list of cards and I am going to return that from my `ToString()`. So I am trying to set up delegation here.

So anytime I call `System.Console.WriteLine(deck);` it should call my `ToString()` and I want to delegate printing to the `ToString()` function that belongs to the list of cards like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Deck deck = new Deck();
        System.Console.WriteLine(deck);
    }
}

public class Deck {
   public List<Card> Cards = new List<Card>();

public Deck() {
  string[] ranks = { "Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five" };
  string[] suits = { "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Spades" };

  foreach (string suit in suits) {
      foreach (string rank in ranks) {
          Card card = new Card(rank, suit);
          Cards.Add(card);
      }
  }
}
  
  public override string ToString()
  {
      return Cards.ToString();
  }
}
```

When I try running it, I see what I thought would be a whole bunch of instances of `[Card]` over and over again, but what actually got printed out was `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Card]`one time. I don’t know why`System.Collections.Generic.List`1` printed out with `[Card]`.

So my guess is that I returned or almost returned a representation of that list of cards, however, when I called `ToString()` on the list of cards that in turn called `ToString()` on my Card class as well which creates a huge chain of delegation from the very top level `ToString()` gets called and that calls the card `ToString()` and that in turn calls `ToString()` on the `Card` class as well.

So I thought I would define a `ToString()` function on the `Card` class itself and from there I can return a string representation of the cards and that's what I attempted to do like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Deck deck = new Deck();
        System.Console.WriteLine(deck);
    }
}

public class Deck {
   public List<Card> Cards = new List<Card>();

public Deck() {
  string[] ranks = { "Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five" };
  string[] suits = { "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Spades" };

  foreach (string suit in suits) {
      foreach (string rank in ranks) {
          Card card = new Card(rank, suit);
          Cards.Add(card);
      }
  }
}
  
  public override string ToString()
  {
      return Cards.ToString();
  }
}

public class Card {
    // properties
    public string suit { get; set; }
    public string rank { get; set; }
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
      return $"{rank} of {suit}"; 
    }

    public Card(string rank, string suit){
       //initializations
       this.rank = rank;
       this.suit = suit;
    }
    
}
```

But that's not what happens, I expected to see printed up something like `[Ace of Diamonds, Two of Diamonds...` and so on, but instead I continue to get `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Card]`

I attempted to follow this documentation for assistance:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8

but I found it to be a bit overwhelming on my first week of C#.

I also tried to follow Enigmativity [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33312775/why-is-my-array-of-cards-empty) but I am still unable to figure this out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47412183/1070452

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List.ToString() does not iterate over all the elements in the list, calling their toString() method. You have to do that yourself.

```
public Deck() {
  string[] ranks = { "Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five" };
  string[] suits = { "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Spades" };

  foreach (string suit in suits) {
      foreach (string rank in ranks) {
          Card card = new Card(rank, suit);
          Cards.Add(card);
      }
  }
}

  public override string ToString()
  {
      string s = "[";
      foreach (var card in Cards) {
        s += card.ToString() + ",";
      }
      s += "]";
      return s;
  }
}
```

Comment: weirdev, for your answer I am getting `error CS1002: ; expected` for that closing curly brace on that `foreach` and thank you for teaching me that I have to manually iterate.

Comment: weirdev, change your `card.toString()` to `card.ToString()`, I already did on my end and I did not know we could use `var` in C#, another lesson for me.

Comment: +1, because your code is the fastest. I did some tests and revealed that your code is, at the average, 1.5-4.5 times faster than mine (see my answer). Looks like with Linq we can significantly reduce code noise but pay a little cost (negligible amount) anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You should change your `ToString()` method inside the `Deck` class to [`String.Join()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8) the results instead:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return "[" + string.Join(", ", Cards.Select(c => c.ToString())) + "]";
}
```

Which gives the following results:

```
[Ace of Diamonds, Two of Diamonds, Three of Diamonds, Four of Diamonds, Five of Diamonds, Ace of Hearts, Two of Hearts, Three of Hearts, Four of Hearts, Five of Hearts, Ace of Clubs, Two of Clubs, Three of Clubs, Four of Clubs, Five of Clubs, Ace of Spades, Two of Spades, Three of Spades, Four of Spades, Five of Spades]
```

As seen in the docs, the method signature looks something like the following:

```
string Join (string separator, IEnumerable<string> values);
```

So we need to pass a string delimiter and a `IEnumerable<string>` collection. We simply give `", "` as the delimiter and we extract the `ToString()` from each string in the collection with LINQ using [`Enumerable.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 1):

I did it with Linq `Aggregate` and [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"[{Cards.Select(a => a.ToString()).Aggregate((b, c) => $"{b}, {c}")}]";
    }
```

Comment: Did you test this?  it looks like a syntax error to me.

Comment: Could you post your error please.

Comment: You have a quoted string with quotes in the middle of it that are not escaped -- I do not believe this will compile.  I don't have an error -- I did not have to put it in a compiler.