# What is Application Domain in .NET and what is its need?

Tags: c#, .net

#### Duplicate:

> [What is AppDomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574708/what-is-appdomain)

---

What is Application Domain in .NET and what is its need?

---

#### See Also:

> [Usage of AppDomain in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665668/usage-of-appdomain-in-c/666122)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very nice and short explanation here:
http://codebetter.com/blogs/raymond.lewallen/archive/2005/04/03/61190.aspx
Hope it helps ;)