How does UseRandomizedStringHashAlgorithm help against hash flooding attacks?
I read this article about GetHashCode().
It talks about how randomizing the hash function can help prevent hash flooding attacks.
Stephen Toub also said in a comment, the reason to use a random hash function is for:

Security, prevention against DoS attacks, etc.

I'm struggling to understand why this is the case.
According to the docs for UseRandomizedStringHashAlgorithm:

The common language runtime computes hash codes for strings on a per
application domain basis. Identical strings in different application
domains and in different processes will have different hash codes.

If the same hash function is being used while the application is running, then doesn't that mean bad actors can find collissions and use these to perform a hash flooding attack?
Or have I misunderstood what "per application domain basis" means?
Is it one application domain that is in use while an ASP.NET web service is running?

From the wiki on Hash Flooding Attacks:

To execute such an attack, the attacker sends the server multiple
pieces of data that hash to the same value and then tries to get the
server to perform slow lookups.

In short: Making the hash code unique per execution / application domain prevents this, because the attacker will be unable to predict the hash codes in advance.

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/574711/2063755, app-domain means per "program". If you have an ASP.NET web service that has been running for  2 weeks, then doesn't that mean the hash function has remained the same for those 2 weeks?

@DavidKlempfner Yes, but what matters is it's a different one than on the attacker's machine, so he has no way of predicting it.
